# Python logging from multiple processes

Tags: python, sockets, file-io, multiprocessing

I have a possibly long running program that currently has 4 processes, but could be configured to have more.  I have researched [logging from multiple processes](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) using python's `logging` and am using the SocketHandler approach discussed [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network).  I never had any problems having a single logger (no sockets), but from what I read I was told it would fail eventually and unexpectedly.  As far as I understand its unknown what will happen when you try to write to the same file at the same time.  My code essentially does the following:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def monitor(...):
    # Spawn child processes with os.fork()
    # os.wait() and act accordingly

def main():
    log_server_pid = os.fork()
    if log_server_pid == 0:
        # Create a LogRecordSocketServer (daemon)
        ...
        sys.exit(0)
    # Add SocketHandler to root logger
    ...
    monitor(<configuration stuff>)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**So my questions are:** Do I need to create a new `log` object after each `os.fork()`?  What happens to the existing global `log` object?

With doing things the way I am, am I even getting around the problem that I'm trying to avoid (multiple open files/sockets)?  Will this fail and why will it fail (I'd like to be able to tell if future similar implementations will fail)?

Also, in what way does the "normal" (one `log=` expression) method of logging to one file from multiple processes fail? Does it raise an IOError/OSError?  Or does it just not completely write data to the file?

If someone could provide an answer or links to help me out, that would be great.  Thanks.

**FYI**:
I am testing on Mac OS X Lion and the code will probably end up running on a CentOS 6 VM on a Windows machine (if that matters).  Whatever solution I use does not need to work on Windows, but should work on a Unix based system.

**UPDATE:** This question has started to move away from logging specific behavior and is more in the realm of what does linux do with file descriptors during forks.  I pulled out one of my college textbooks and it seems that if you open a file in append mode from two processes (not before a fork) that they will both be able to write to the file properly as long as your write doesn't exceed the actual kernel buffer (although line buffering might need to be used, still not sure on that one).  This creates 2 file table entries and one v-node table entry.  Opening a file then forking isn't supposed to work, but it seems to as long as you don't exceed the kernel buffer as before (I've done it in a previous program).

So I guess, if you want platform independent multi-processing logging you use sockets and create a new SocketHandler after each fork to be safe as Vinay suggested below (that should work everywhere).  For me, since I have strong control over what OS my software is being run on, I think I'm going to go with one global `log` object with a FileHandler (opens in append mode by default and line buffered on most OSs).  The documentation for [`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) says "A negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If omitted, the system default is used." or I could just create my own logging stream to be sure of line buffering.  And just to be clear, I'm ok with:

```
# Process A
a_file.write("A\n")
a_file.write("A\n")
# Process B
a_file.write("B\n")
```

producing...

```
A\n
B\n
A\n
```

as long as it doesn't produce...

```
AB\n
\n
A\n
```

**Vinay**(or anyone else), how wrong am I?  Let me know.  Thanks for any more clarity/sureness you can provide.

Comment: Threads and locks are useful for things like this...

Comment: I need separate processes as the children are communicating with external devices that should be as "quick" as possible.

Comment: I think that you might get expected behaviour by luck: A\nB\nA\n rather than AB\n\nA\n. However, in my view the approach of writing in multiple child processes to file handles inherited from a parent process is not guaranteed to be well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to create a new log object after each os.fork()? What happens to the existing global log object?

AFAIK the global log object remains pointing to the same logger in parent and child processes. So you shouldn't need to create a new one. However, I think you should create and add the `SocketHandler` after the `fork()` in `monitor()`, so that the socket server has four distinct connections, one to each child process. If you don't do this, then the child processes forked off in monitor() will inherit the SocketHandler and its socket handle from their parent, but I don't know for sure that it will misbehave. The behaviour is likely to be OS-dependent and you may be lucky on OSX.

> With doing things the way I am, am I even getting around the problem that I'm trying to avoid (multiple open files/sockets)? Will this fail and why will it fail (I'd like to be able to tell if future similar implementations will fail)?

I wouldn't expect failure if you create the socket connection to the socket server after the last `fork()` as I suggested above, but I am not sure the behaviour is well-defined in any other case. You refer to multiple open files but I see no reference to opening files in your pseudocode snippet, just opening sockets.

> Also, in what way does the "normal" (one log= expression) method of logging to one file from multiple processes fail? Does it raise an IOError/OSError? Or does it just not completely write data to the file?

I think the behaviour is not well-defined, but one would expect failure modes to present as interspersed log messages from different processes in the file, e.g.

```
Process A writes first part of its message
Process B writes its message
Process A writes second part of its message
```

**Update:** If you use a `FileHandler` in the way you described in your comment, things will not be so good, due to the scenario I've described above: process A and B both begin pointing at the end of file (because of the append mode), but thereafter things can get out of sync because (e.g. on a multiprocessor, but even potentially on a uniprocessor), one process can (preempt another and) write to the shared file handle before another process has finished doing so.

Comment: When I said multiple files I meant if I had done a basic FileHandler instead of a SocketHandler.  I talked to a co-worker and he mentioned that if logging opens up a FileHandler in append mode on linux that I should be ok (one log object, one file handler, multiple forks).  Thoughts?  And creating SocketHandlers after a fork makes sense.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because of the creating of the SocketHandler after the fork, but I still disagree with append mode (kernel should make append writes atomic).